# Setup RAID-1 in Kickstart file with 1 Disk

Tags: linux, raid, kickstart

Is it possible to setup RAID-1 on a system with only 1 disk and later add the second one?
I read the instructions from Red Hat and there is an option to add --spare=
I tried this with the code below

```
part raid.11 --size=1024  --asprimary --ondrive=${DISKA}
part raid.12 --size=512   --ondrive=${DISKA}
part raid.11 --size=12000  --grow  --ondrive=${DISKA}

raid /boot     --fstype=xfs --device=example --level=RAID1 --spares=1 raid.11
raid /boot/efi --fstype=efi --device=example --level=RAID1 --spares=1 raid.12
raid pv.01.    --fstype=xfs --device=example --level=RAID1 --spares=1 raid.13
```

but gives me the error message below during the installation and it fails:

RAID level raid1 requires that device have at least 2 members

Thank you

Comment: is `raid.11` on 3th line a copy/paste error ? (should be `raid.13`? )

Comment: `mdadm` can do it with giving the 2nd drive as `missing` (to be added later), or by using `--force`. kickstart would have to allow either one, but the kickstart documentation does not mention it (explicitely mentions needs at least 2), so you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not supported, the requirement for two disks for RAID1 comes from the storage library the installer uses and the `--force` option for `mdadm` is not supported. It is also not possible to pre-create this type of array manually and then use it as installation target -- see [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1195522) report and [this (closed) RFE](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1967232) on Fedora bugzilla.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a filesystem with inbuilt RAID functionality instead of `mdadm`, it's possible (for example BTRFS, ZFS). I recommend using BTRFS, as it's easy to manage.

How it works:

Make sure you have `btrfs-progs` installed and you've updated grub and initramfs (on debian):

```
sudo apt install btrfs-progs && sudo update-grub
```

You just format your volume with btrfs, like so:

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs --label boot /dev/sda2
```

That's it.

If you want to convert this single volume to a RAID1 (works online, even for root filesystem), just do (let's assume it's mounted in `/boot`):

```
sudo btrfs device add /dev/sdb2 /boot
sudo btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1 -dconvert=raid1 /boot
```

You can add multiple volumes to a RAID array in BTRFS, they don't need to have the same size, like so:

```
sudo btrfs device add /dev/sdc2 /boot
sudo btrfs device add /dev/sdd2 /boot
sudo btrfs balance start /boot
```

BTRFS RAID arrays can be mounted using either any of the device-names, either the UUID or either the label of the filesystem. I recommend using label for mounting.

```
sudo mount LABEL=boot /boot
```

You can also remove a volume from the RAID (even online, just make sure the remaining array/volume has enough free space), like so:

```
sudo btrfs device remove /dev/sdc2 /
```

If you want to convert your RAID back to a "single" mode, you do:

```
sudo btrfs balance start --force -sconvert=single -mconvert=single -dconvert=single /boot
```

"single" mode is similar to JBOD, but on filesystem level.

All BTRFS modes (single, dup, raid) are working on filesystem level, not on block level like `mdadm`, this has many advantages, like faster replication and more data safety. It's also easier to use and a lot more failsafe than `mdadm`, especially when using arrays with many volumes.

The "dup" mode is essential a mix between "single" mode and RAID1, it's similar to a JBOD with metadata and/or data being duplicated. "dup" mode is good for traditional rotating disks.

```
# this will duplicate meta data only
sudo btrfs balance start -mconvert=dup -dconvert=single /boot

# this will duplicate meta data and data, like in a RAID1
sudo btrfs balance start -mconvert=dup -dconvert=dup /boot
```

Please read the manpages for BTRFS and inform yourself about the pro and contra about using BTRFS and how to handle some special cases like large databases or handling of many small frequently used files.

PS don't use BTRFS RAID5 and also don't use BTRFS RAID6, it's experimental and not safe to use, that's not a joke, don't use these RAID modes!

PPS grub supports booting from BTRFS, so you don't need a seprate `/boot` partition

PPPS BTRFS supports inbuilt LVM and snapshots